# Unable to mount XFS after rescue, why?

Tags: linux, mount, gpt, xfs, ddrescue

I am facing a strange problem with XFS file system. Below is the exact scenario:

I'd a corrupt 2TB disk with XFS (I/O error), so with that decided to rescue data from old disk to new disk.

I'd run `ddrescue` to rescue data to a new disk. `ddrescue` finished successfully except 204kB data. After that I was trying to mount the new disk but no luck. Below I am posting the `ddrescue` result and mount error. Please help me to solve the issue. I'll be really grateful.

`ddrescue` result:

```
# ddrescue --force -n /dev/sdc /dev/sde  
GNU ddrescue 1.16  
About to copy 2198 GB from /dev/sdc to /dev/sde  
Starting positions:  
Infile = 0 B, outfile = 0 B  
Copy Block size: 128 sectors Initial skip size: 128 sectors Sectors size: 512 Bytes  

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt  
rescued : 2198 GB, errsize : 204 kB, current rate : 1560 B/s  
Ipos : 68699 MB, errors : 15, average rate : 29103 KB/s  
Opos : 68699 MB, time since last successful read : 0 s  
Finished
```

*fdisk*

```
# fdisk -l  
Disk /dev/sdc: 2198.3 GB, 2198352166912 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267267 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System

/dev/sdc1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sde: 2198.3 GB, 2198352166912 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267267 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System  
/dev/sde1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee EFI GPT
```

*ls -l /dev/sd**

```
# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  0 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sda  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  1 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sda1  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  2 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sda2  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  3 Feb 27 18:00 /dev/sda3  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  4 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sda4  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  5 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sda5  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 16 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sdb  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 17 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sdb1  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 32 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sdc  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 48 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sdd  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 49 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sdd1  
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 64 Feb 28 02:00 /dev/sde
```

#### Inside # fdisk -l command /dev/dec1 and /dev/sde1 missing

*parted print*

```
# parted -i /dev/sde print
Model: DELL PERC 5/i (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sde: 2198GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  
 1      32.3kB  2198GB  2198GB  primary  xfs                 

Information: Don't forget to update /etc/fstab, if necessary.
```

*Attempting to mount*

```
# mount -t xfs /dev/sde /mnt/mail3
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try  
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

*dmesg, /var/log/messages, & file  output*

```
# dmesg | tail  
XFS: bad magic number  
XFS: SB validate failed  

# tail -f /var/log/messages  
Feb 28 04:09:29 mail kernel: XFS: bad magic number  
Feb 28 04:09:29 mail kernel: XFS: SB validate failed  

# file -s /dev/sde  
/dev/sde: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xee, starthead 0, startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011
```

**Please help and it will be highly appreciated.**

*Attempting to mount as hfsplus*

```
# mount -t hfsplus /dev/sde1 /mnt/mail3  
mount: special device /dev/sde1 does not exist

# mount -t hfsplus /dev/sde /mnt/mail3  
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde,  
missing codepage or other error  
In some cases useful info is found in syslog  
- try dmesg | tail  or so

# dmesg | tail  
hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock

# tail -f /var/log/messages  
Feb 28 02:40:26 mail kernel: hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

Comment: if it's XFS, why `-t hfsplus`?

Comment: Hi @frostschutz thank you very much for your reply. I am getting bellow error when using `-t xfs`

`[root@mail]# mount -t xfs /dev/sde /mnt/mail3`  
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde,  
missing codepage or other error  
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try  
dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: Hi @frost Below is the output of dmesg: 

`[root@mail]# dmesg | tail`  
XFS: bad magic number  
XFS: SB validate failed  

`[root@mail]# tailf /var/log/messages`

Feb 28 04:08:04 mail kernel: XFS: bad magic number
Feb 28 04:08:04 mail kernel: XFS: SB validate failed

Comment: `[root@mail ~]# file -s /dev/sde`
/dev/sde: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xee, starthead 0, startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011

`[root@mail ~]# file -s /dev/sde1`
/dev/sde1: ERROR: cannot open `/dev/sde1' (No such file or directory)

Comment: anybody out there to help on this issue??

Comment: Exactly the PROBLEM that i'm facing right now. Someone please help.